# How to save excel file in .bat?

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, cmd

I have this Code in Macro that i use to save files in csv. Is it possible now that i save this file in .bat Format ?

This is the Code i use :

```
Public Sub Export_File_as_CSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")     
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                      
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\User_Tableau.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
Sheets("Export").Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Otherwise i have to save it in Excel and then again to convert in .txt file and then in .bat file. I try to automate all this steps with macro and  save it  .bat file.

Your help is much appriciated !

Thank you

Comment: This seems like a request for code.

Comment: Yeah some improvments in Code i guess, i tried to save as **.bat** file and Change the _FileFormat:=xlbat_ but it wont work.

Comment: no, the syntax of a macro will not be recognised by `cmd`. It is most definitely not _"some imporvements"_ it is a complete re-write in batch format.

Comment: just as another side note, a `.csv` is a comma-separated values file and not excel. Excel saves in binary, not plain text.

Comment: Hint: Take a look at VBScript. It will help you achieve this if you intend to run it as an external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if someone Needs it in the future, i found the solution ! Apparently i was really close.
This is the changes i made and it worked.

Code :

```
Public Sub Export_File_as_BAT()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

'Call Artifficial_Groups
'Call filterout_for_export
'Call RemoveDuplicates
'Call Allocate_BEZ

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export")     
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                      
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\User_Tableau.bat", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
Sheets("Export").Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Better to use `wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:= Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\User_Tableau.bat", FileFor...`